# Angular “Unknown provider” error when using custom Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am using angular 1.5 with typescript. Facing `Unknown provider: testNameFilterFilterProvider <- testNameFilterFilter`

Here is my existing code

```
export class TestNameFilter extends AbstractFilter {
    public static factory($injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService): Function {
      return new TestNameFilter($injector).filter;
    }

    public constructor($injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService) {
      super("TestNameFilter", $injector);
    }

    public filter = (text: string, length: any, end: any): string => {
      let state: string = text;
      state = this.toSentenceCase(state);
      return state;
    }

  }
```

**Registration**

```
angular.module("myApp").filter(
    "testNameFilter",
    [
      "$injector",
      ($injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService) => new TestNameFilter($injector).filter,
    ]
  );
```

**HTML**

```
 <select 
        ng-options="item as (test.name | testNameFilter)
                    for test in testing">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Probably specific js file is not added/loaded.

Comment: @james required js file is loading.